# Covariant(out) & generic type kotlin

Tags: generics, inheritance, interface, kotlin, covariant

In Java I can do this:

```
    interface BaseInterface {}

    interface ExtendsInterface extends BaseInterface {}

    public interface ProblemInterface<E extends BaseInterface> {
        void method(E baseInterface);
    }

    class Main {
        public static void main (String [ ] args) {
            ProblemInterface<ExtendsInterface> problemInterfaceExtendsInterface = new ProblemInterface<ExtendsInterface>() {
                @Override
                public void method(ExtendsInterface baseInterface) {}
            };

             ProblemInterface<? extends BaseInterface> problemInterfaceBaseInterface = problemInterfaceExtendsInterface;
        }
    }
```

In Kotlin:

```
    interface BaseInterface

    interface ExtendsInterface: BaseInterface

    interface ProblemInterface<out E : BaseInterface> {
       fun method(baseInterface: E)
    }       

    val problemInterfaceExtendsInterface: ProblemInterface<ExtendsInterface> = object : ProblemInterface<ExtendsInterface> {
        override fun method(baseInterface: ExtendsInterface) {}
    }

    val problemInterfaceBaseInterface: ProblemInterface<BaseInterface> = problemInterfaceExtendsInterface
```

But the problem is: using covariant (out) but Type parameter occurs in 'in' position

Any idea to solve this?
How I can do to works the same code in Java/Kotlin?
Thanks

Comment: Solve it by declaring `in E` instead of `out E`. Clearly your interface is contravariant with respect to it.

Comment: `out` types cannot appear as arguments of functions. They can only be returned (hence `out`).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik but declaring in E then I can't use val problemInterfaceBaseInterface: ProblemInterface<BaseInterface> = problemInterfaceExtendsInterface

Comment: @Strelok I know, I look a solution to use: val problemInterfaceBaseInterface: ProblemInterface<BaseInterface> = problemInterfaceExtendsInterface keeping
 fun method(baseInterface: E) in ProblemInterface interface

Comment: That's because the type system is right and you're wrong: you can't treat a `ProblemInterface<ExtendsInterface>` as if it was a `ProblemInterface<BaseInterface>`. Its `method` doesn't accept all instances of `BaseInterface`.

Comment: I added the same code in Java and works fine, what's wrong with kotlin?

Comment: Nothing wrong with Kotlin, but wrong again with your Java code. Since Java only supports use-site variance declaration, you were allowed to declare `ProblemInterface<? extends BaseInterface>`. Now you can't call `method()` without a compiler error.

Comment: You might also note that `ProblemInterface<E extends BaseInterface>` didn't declare `E` as a covariant type parameter (it's not equivalent to `out E`). It just enforced an upper bound on `E`.